Image background remover in React Native
Need a image background remover like remove.bg. If any library suggested or I have to use Machine Learning concepts for it.
I tried this lib react-native-background-remover but this lib can only remove background of human body.

This is not an easy feat...

this is asking for recommendations. [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic]
